# Problema mostrando resultados de peticion http => formbuilder [Angular 6]

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy intentando mostrar los resultados de una consulta `http post` en el formulario a través `FormBuilder` de Angular, el caso es que en el `.observable()` puedo imprimir la información, pero no la puedo sacar de esa función.

```
public listado;

  public centro:any = {
      nombre: "nombre",
      telefono: "78945623",
      municipio: "municipio",
      direccion: "direccion"
  }

ngOnInit() {

      //obtenemos datos del centro.
      this.datoscentro();

      // build the form model
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      'nombre': [ this.centro.nombre  ,   [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      'telefono': [this.centro.telefono , [ Validators.required ]],
      'municipio': [this.centro.municipio , [ Validators.required ]],
      'direccion': [this.centro.direccion , [ Validators.required ]]
        )
      })
    }

  //obtenemos datos centro
  datoscentro(){
    this.crudProducto.datoscentro(this.id_centro)
    .map((response) => response.json() )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.listado = data;
      this.centro.nombre = "este resultado no sale";
      // console.log(this.listado);
    });
  }
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué cuando a `centro.nombre` le asigno un valor no aparece en el `form builder`?

Comment: ¿Angular 6? ¿Y no estás usando HttpClient para hacer las consultas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque la llamada a `this.crudProducto.datoscentro()` es asíncrona y, por tanto, no tienes los datos hasta después de que `ngInit()` haya terminado de ejecutarse. La solución es rellenar el formulario **después** de obtener los datos:

```
ngOnInit() {

      //obtenemos datos del centro.
      this.datoscentro();

      // build the form model

    }

  //obtenemos datos centro
  datoscentro(){
    this.crudProducto.datoscentro(this.id_centro)
    .map((response) => response.json() )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.listado = data;
      this.centro.nombre = "este resultado no sale";

      //Ahora que tenemos los datos, rellenamos el formulario
      this.populateForm();
    });
  }

populateForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      'nombre': [ this.centro.nombre  ,   [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      'telefono': [this.centro.telefono , [ Validators.required ]],
      'municipio': [this.centro.municipio , [ Validators.required ]],
      'direccion': [this.centro.direccion , [ Validators.required ]]
      });

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha sido muy útil